# How to fix 'Cannot convert value of type' error in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

Cannot convert value of type '(MenuType).Type' to expected argument type 'MenuType'
I watched youtube and combine that code and mine, This error occurred when I added my code. what's wrong??? It worked well before adding my code.

```
import UIKit

enum MenuType: Int{
    case home
    case search
    case profile
}

class SideMenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    var didTapMenuType : ((MenuType) -> Void)?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let menuType = MenuType(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }
        dismiss(animated: true){[weak self] in
            self?.didTapMenuType?(MenuType)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably `self?.didTapMenuType?(menuType)` with small m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter must be the instance `menuType` (lowercase) not the type `MenuType`

```
    dismiss(animated: true){[weak self] in
        self?.didTapMenuType?(menuType)
    }
```

Comment: Wow,,,,, I couldn't find it at all. Thank you so much.